# Bootstrap modal won't show up in laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I'm trying to summon a modal window as a confirm delete for products/categories/users/pages admin can add and edit. However the window isn't showing up.
This is one of the pages the modal should show up in:

```
@extends('admin.atemplate')
@section('admin-content')

<h1> Categories </h1>
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right mb-3" href="{{url('admin/categories/create')}}"> Add new category</a>
@if($categories->isEmpty())
<p> There are no categories</p>
@else
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Slug</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <img class="admin-thumbnail" src="{{asset('storage/' . $category->image)}}" alt="{{$category->name}}">
                </th>
                <td class="align-middle"> {{$category->name}} </td>
                <td class="align-middle"> {{$category->slug}} </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <a href="{{url('admin/categories/' . $category->id . '/edit')}}">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chevron-double-up" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 3.707 2.354 9.354a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l6-6z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 7.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    **<a class="open-modal" data-id="{{$category->id}}" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> WAIT </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you SURE you want to delete this?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"> I changed my mind </button>
                <form id="delete-form" method="post" data-route="{{url('admin/categories/')}}" action="">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Yes </button>
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>**
@endif
@endsection
```

(added ** to show where the modal starts)

here is the javascript:

```
'use strict';
$(function() {
    $('.minus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('.plus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('a.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this);
        var url = that.attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'get',
        success:function (response){
            if (Number(response)){
                $('#mini-cart span').text(response);
                $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success').text('Product was added!');
            }else{
                $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-danger').text('Action could not be completed!');
            }
        }
        }).fail(function(){
            $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-danger').text('Action could not be completed!');
        }).always(function(){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('#alert').slideUp();    
            }, 3000);  
            });
        });
    $('#add-to-cart').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefualt();
        var that = $(this);
            url = that.attr('action'),
            data = that.serialize();
        
    $.post(url, data, function(response){
        if (Number(response)){
            $('#mini-cart span').text(response);
            $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success').text('Product was added!');
        }else{
            $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-danger').text('Action could not be completed!');
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-danger').text('Action could not be completed!');
    }).always(function(){
                window.setTimeOut(function(){
                $('#alert').slideUp();    
                }, 3000);
            });
        });
    $('product-quantity').on('change', debounce (function (){
        var that = $(this),    
            parent = that.parents('.update-cart');
            url = parent.attr('action'),
            data = parent.serialize();
        
    $.post(url, data, function(response){
        //JSON.pharse(response);
        if (Number(response.cart_count)){
            $('#mini-cart span').text(response.cart_count);
            $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success').text('Cart was updated!');
            that.parents ('tR').find('.product-total').text(response.product_total);
            $('.cart-total').text(response.cart_total);
    
    } else {
            $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-danger').text('Action could not be completed!');
        }
    }, 'json').fail(function(){
        $('#alert').slideDown().removeClass().addClass('alert alert-danger').text('Action could not be completed!');
    }).always(function(){
                window.setTimeOut(function(){
                $('#alert').slideUp();    
                }, 3000);
        });
    }, 500));
    
    $('a.delete-product').on('click', function(){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?')
    });
    $('a.delete-cart').on('click', function(){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to empty your cart?')
    });
    $('.open-modal').on('click', function(){
        var that = $(this),
            id = that.data('id'),
            name = that.data('name'),
            form = $('#delete-form'),
            route = form.data('route');

            form.attr('action', route + '/' + id);
            $('#confirmModal .modal-body').text('Are you sure you want to delete ' + name)
        });
    });    
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Jquery and JavaScript are added at the bottom of a template file, and other functions in script are working so it doesn't seem like a placement problem.

Comment: check if you have js errors